# Identify the subject and predicative verbs of this clause

Tags: clauses

Can you help me in locating the subject and the predicative verb of this dependent clause?

> If by the time you graduate you still can't read and write well

Comment: We ask users to make an honest effort at answering their own question before asking others for help.  Can you offer your own thoughts about what these verbs are, and why?

Comment: There are two clauses in that "dependent clause". Both contain verbs and subjects. Which one are you talking about? And how much good will it do you to know the subjects if you can't tell what clauses there are?

Comment: I mean the both clauses sir.. I think "you" and "you" on the second clause are the subjects "graduate" and "can't" are the verbs. Is this correct or not?